# Can't change background image with JS/ Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input box that takes the web URL of any image and then i have a button that change the CSS background image. The code is good the way i look at it but it isnt working. Can you point out the fault.

**HTML**

```
<input name="webURL" type="text" id="webURL" value="" placeholder="Or paste a web URL"><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit-btn" class="webBtn" value="Upload it."/>
```

**JS**

```
$('.webBtn').click(function(){
    $('#uploadedPhoto').css('background-image', "url($('#webURL').attr('value'))");
    $('#webURL').attr('value', URL);
});
```

Comment: where is the uploadedPhoto? and "url(....)" is just string

Comment: `$('#uploadedPhoto').css('background-image', "url(" + $('#webURL').val() + ")");`

Comment: @Iv0gun uploadedPhoto is enhoed with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input name="webURL" type="text" id="webURL" value="" placeholder="Or paste a web URL"><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit-btn" class="webBtn" value="Upload it."/>

<div id="uploadedPhoto" style="width:200px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $('.webBtn').click(function(){
        var upUrl = $('#webURL').val();

        $('#uploadedPhoto').css({'background-image' : 'url(' + upUrl + ')','background-repeat': 'no-repeat'});
        $('#webURL').attr('value', URL);
  });
</script>
```

Try this. Should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this mate

```
$('.webBtn').click(function(){
        $('#uploadedPhoto').css('background-image',"url("+$('#webURL').attr('value')+")");
        $('#webURL').attr('value', URL);
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8ffj1aw/)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't do string interpolation.

This is a literal string containing a jQuery selector.

```
"url($('#webURL').attr('value'))"
```

Instead, you need to build the correct string up by concatenating the various parts:

```
"url(" + $('#webURL').attr('value') + ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this working code -

```
$('.webBtn').click(function(){
    $('#uploadedPhoto').css('background-image',"url("+$('#webURL').val()+")");
    $('#webURL').val('');
});
```

Demo - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8x5jdwj)